# In Riemann Sum, how $dx$ result of $\frac{b - a}{n}$, cannot evenly divide into the interval $b - a$.

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

Doubt in explanation of Riemann Sum explanation given in book "Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach".

explaining Definite Integral,

I couldn't understand how the value $dx$ (the width of a vertical strip/rectangle )
obtained from $dx = \frac{b - a}{n}$, cannot divide evenly into the interval length $b - a$.

check the calculation in below link calculated $n$-th value is not getting greater than $b$. It can evenly divided.
http://jsbin.com/bogiwaxina/edit?js,console

Can anyone explain me a case, where the calculate dx cannot get evenly divided ?
[image]

Comment: Even without such unreliable means as javascript, it is clear that $a< b$, $n>0$,  and $dx=(b-a)/n$ implies $a\le a+i\cdot dx\le b$ for $0\le i\le n$, with equality on the left for $i=0$ and on the right for $i=n$.

Comment: I have updated my question, I am not able imagine the case where dx cause remainder / or extra rectangle which doesn't fit inside [a, b]

Comment: It doesn't matter that it does not divide it evenly. This division is a quotient of real numbers. Remember also that you are going to consider $n$ to go to infinity. This limit is the key for the integral to actually give you the area under the curve

Comment: It can always be divided evenly. The Riemann sum theorem says that it **does not have to be**, that is it **may** be divided unevenly, we still get the right limit (the integral) if the largest length goes to zero.

Comment: yeah, I understood wrongly thank you @A.Γ.

Comment: @A.Γ. shall I close this question or do you want to add your comment as answer ?

Comment: @sudhnk Nothing wrong with the question, let it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can always be divided evenly. The Riemann sum theorem says that it **does not have** to be, that is, it **may** be divided unevenly, we still get the right limit (the integral) if the largest length goes to zero.